# Install Numpy on multple python version

Tags: software-installation, python, versions

I have installed the numpy module for Python 2.7. However I have three versions (2.4, 2.6 and 2.7) on my system and it has installed on 2.7 only. I presume this is the default python as this is the version the command "which python" gives me in terminal. I am running a python script in another program that defaults to python 2.4. I have two questions:

1. How do I install numpy on the non default version of Python, in my case python2.4. I have consulted the forums and could not find an answer.
2. Can I force another program to run a specfic version of Python when running a python script. From sys.version I can see which python its running, however is there another command I can use to enforce a specific version to run.

Thanks

---

Thanks Don.Joey,

Yes, I have looked at virtual environments and it is the correct way to do this. I understand it will work in the terminal,  however will this work when another program is calling the Python script?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). They allow you to have different version of a package. They also make it possible to have several versions of python live together.

Make a virtual environment that uses 2.4. Install numpy in it. Run your script in that venv (virtual environment). Enjoy.

Comment: Karel, feel free to edit my answer or write your own. I have given the most important pointer. I am not going to solve each and every detail. Thanks for your feedback, though.